# Get list of all user's except first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I were getting a list of all the users like so:

```
@users = User.all
```

How can I get the same thing but leaving out the first user on that last??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
@users = User.all[1..-1]
```

Comment: Thank you @thorsten. I'll accept the answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Active Record last method.

```
 n =  User.count -1;
 @users = User.last(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset)

```
@users = User.offset(1)
```